# Unable to print on a HP 2600n on SBS2003 over Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, printing, hp, windows-sbs-2003

I have a SBS2003 with a HP 2600n installed on it. I am able to print from the server, the test page prints. From my computer, Windows 7 Pro, I am unable to print any document...

What would be your suggestions?!

Any takers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer but a statement of fact.  This printer is a host based printer which means that it is cheaper and will give you all sorts of problems as it isn't really designed to be shared on a network oddly enough.  One thing that I have done with this printer was to disable bi-directional communication which resolved some issues were we having.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... check the drivers on the server and the client?

Answer (score 0):

I have had some luck using the HP universal print driver on both the server and client in this situation, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: Don't think the universal print driver is supported with host based printers.